# If...else statements not working as expected

Tags: python-3.x, asynchronous, discord.py

I'm actually trying to create a simple Discord bot using discord.py. The problem comes here, when  I try to execute this code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

myid = 3586xxxxxxxxxx
cliente = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!!")

@cliente.command()
async def clear(ctx, amount):

    if myid == ctx.author.id:

        print("Entering If statement")  # This is printed
        await ctx.channel.purge(limit=int(amount))  # This is not executed

    else:

        await ctx.channel.send("You don't have enough permissions.")  # This is executed
```

The output makes no sense, when I run "!!clear 2" on my server, the program enters the If and prints "Entering the If statement", It doesn't remove anything, and then the bot sends the message inside the else.

I'm so confused right now :s

Comment: just because I've been caught before.  check to see if you "the code" has permissions to purge.  it could be the ctx saying no, not you.

Comment: You are using await -- that means things don't happen in sequence.  It could be that it has not finished one task (for the first message you see) when it prints the 2nd message.  If you use await don't expect things to happen synchronously you are specifically allowing for asynchronous behavoir.

Comment: What can I do then? Trying to remove the "await" keywords results in this kind of errors: "RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Messageable.send' was never awaited".

Comment: The purge method works fine in other cases, so I don't think It's a purge problem @arcee123 .

Comment: Do you have any `on_message` event or error handling that could be interfering? If you run just the code you have here, do you still see this behavior?

Comment: I just have one more function (on_ready) written, It just prints "Bot is now working" when the bot starts, so It does not interfer in any way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know why It didn't work, but hey!, I found a great alternative that consists on using usernames. I'll leave an example:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

myuname = "User#1234"
cliente = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!!")

@cliente.command()
async def clear(ctx, amount):

    if myuname == str(ctx.author): # For some reason using str() is neccessary or It won't work properly.

        print("Entering If statement")  # This is printed
        await ctx.channel.purge(limit=int(amount))  # This is not executed

    else:

        await ctx.channel.send("You don't have enough permissions")
```

And that's It, hope It helped someone :)